# Dataflow Pipeline - Using dynamic param or query

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to create a dataflow pipeline template, which required me to read data from bigquery. So what i need is to make my query dynamic using like `Instant.now()` but it seems the query is locked when creating the template

```
  Some Code HERE
  Some Code HERE
  Some Code HERE
 
  pipeline.apply("ReadFromBigQuery",
      BigQueryIO.read(new DataTransformer(MyCustomObject.getQuery()))
          .fromQuery(spec.getQuery())
          .usingStandardSql()
          .withQueryLocation("US")
          .withoutValidation()
  ).apply("do Something 1",
      Combine.globally(new CombineIterableAccumulatorFn<MyCustomObject2>())
  ).apply("do Something 2",
      ParDo.of(new SendToKenshoo(param, param2)
  );
```

My query is like this

```
SELECT * FROM `my-project-id.my-dataset.my-view` where PARTITIONTIME between TIMESTAMP('@currentDate') and  TIMESTAMP('@tomorrowDate')
```

need to replace that @currentDate and @tomorrowDate using `Instant.now()` or any time function
please give me some example

note : i need to change the date on the code instead on query level like this

```
SELECT * FROM `my-project-id.my-dataset.my-view` where PARTITIONTIME between DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY) and  CURRENT_DATE()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you're sending those parameters to the query (via value provider, etc). However, I wouldn't recommend using templates for that because you need dynamic inputs. If you want to do that, I would use Flex Templates: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/using-flex-templates